# Use String.Format to create regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, string-interpolation

Essentially I have a string for interpolation: `Log_{0}.txt` and the `{0}` is replaced with an integer during a different process. So the results could be something like `Log_123.txt` or `Log_53623432.txt`.

I'm trying to use `string.Format()` and replace `{0}` with a regular expression that checks for numbers. Eventually I want to be able to pull those numbers out as well.

I've tried a few different variations on something like this, but I haven't had any luck:

```
var stringFormat = new Regex(string.Format("Log_{0}.txt", @"^\d$"));
```

Also, here's the code that's checking the format:

```
        var fileNameFormat = new Regex(string.Format("Log_{0}.txt", @"^\d+$"));

        var existingFiles = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\projects\\something");

        foreach(var file in existingFiles)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
            if(fileNameFormat.Match(fileName).Success)
            {
                // do something here
            }              
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is in your regex. `^` asserts start of the line and `$` end of the line. Just replace it with `@"\d+"` and it should work.

Optionally you can use `new Regex(string.Format("^Log_{0}.txt$", @"\d+"));` to ensure that no files such as asdffff_Log_13255.txt.temp are matched.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put the plus `+` quantifier maybe?

> + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

```
var stringFormat = new Regex(string.Format("Log_{0}.txt", @"^\d+$"));
```

Comment: Haven't had any luck with that. I updated the question with the code I'm using to check against the regex. Maybe the issue is in there.